# How to deal with single line wrapped into multiple lines in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

For example,

```
int main()
{
        int aa = 1, bb =2, cc = 3;
        int dd = ( (aa + 3 - 1)
                 / bb)
                 << cc;                                                                                                          
        printf("%d\n", dd);
        return 1;
}
```

So I break `int dd` line to multiple lines just to demonstrate.

Then I use gdb to debug.

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at a.c:25
25              int aa = 1, bb =2, cc = 3;
(gdb) n
26              int dd = ( (aa + 3 - 1)
(gdb) n
27                       / bb)
(gdb) n
26              int dd = ( (aa + 3 - 1)
(gdb) n
29              printf("%d\n", dd);
(gdb) n
8
30              return 1;
```

As you can see `int dd` shown multiple times and `<< cc` does not show.

How to avoid this? For example when I type `n` and enter, gdb show the complete `int dd` line once, and when I type `n` again, gdb goes to next line?

Comment: Trying to step through specific points in an expression isn't going to be too successful in general, since the lines on which you've split the expression do not always correspond well with the sequence of instructions that is generated.  I suspect the second display of `int dd = ...` corresponds to the assignment to `dd` which was performed at that point.  If you want more precise sequencing, then split your expression up into multiple statements.

Comment: gdb steps through debugging info chunks created by the compiler. The latter associated a certain block of assembly instructions with a line. So, `/bb` is apparently associated with a division instruction. So, there is no way to do what you want. Use graphical tools (e.g., emacs debug mode) to see where you are. you can also try to use `ctrl-x, ctrl-a` at the debugger prompt to get a terminal view or use the `list` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can do from within GDB because it merely follows the debugging information produced by the compiler. You can see the assembly output with `gcc -g -S -fverbose-asm -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm -o - main.c`. Thanks to the annotations you should be able to get the gist of it even if you don't know assembly.

Here is an excerpt:

```
# main.c:4:         int dd = ( (aa + 3 - 1)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # aa, tmp91
    addl    $2, %eax    #, _1
# main.c:5:                  / bb)
    cltd
    idivl   -8(%rbp)    # bb
    movl    %eax, %edx  # tmp92, _2
# main.c:4:         int dd = ( (aa + 3 - 1)
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax # cc, tmp94
    movl    %eax, %ecx  # tmp94, tmp99
    sall    %cl, %edx   # tmp99, _2
    movl    %edx, %eax  # _2, tmp95
    movl    %eax, -16(%rbp) # tmp95, dd
```

The last block is equivalent to

```
int dd = _2 << cc;
```

Since the result of an operation has to be stored somewhere the shift and assignment are not split. The reference is to the line containing the assignment.

You should rewrite the code to have one operation per statement:

```
int t1 = (aa + 3 - 1);
int t2 = t1 / bb;
int dd = t2 << cc;
```

Here is the corresponding assembly:

```
# main.c:4:     int t1 = (aa + 3 - 1);
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # aa, tmp92
    addl    $2, %eax    #, tmp91
    movl    %eax, -16(%rbp) # tmp91, t1
# main.c:5:     int t2 = t1 / bb;
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax # t1, tmp96
    cltd
    idivl   -8(%rbp)    # bb
    movl    %eax, -20(%rbp) # tmp94, t2
# main.c:6:     int dd = t2 << cc;
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax # cc, tmp100
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx # t2, tmp102
    movl    %eax, %ecx  # tmp100, tmp106
    sall    %cl, %edx   # tmp106, tmp102
    movl    %edx, %eax  # tmp102, tmp101
    movl    %eax, -24(%rbp) # tmp101, dd
```

It is essentially the same as before but now the blocks match the statements perfectly. You can't control the compiler's output but it will try to preserve the boundaries between statements, so that is your best option.